# Query for multiples entities at 1 query

Tags: android, sqlite, greendao

GreenDao has Query support that lets us query the database in a simple manner. I'm looking if its possible to do the following. Lets say that I want to get from the sqlite db 3 entities from a different tables in one query.

Something like:

```
[SELECT FROM TABLE1....] OR 
[SELECT FROM TABLE2 ....] OR 
[SELECT FROM TABLE3....]
```

in greenDao each query object is attached to dao object so I'm a little skeptical about it

Answer (score 0):

so I found the solution for that problem. 
In sql you can acquire it with IN operator.

In GreenDao you'll need to do it like this:

```
getDao().queryBuilder().where(Dao.Properties.Id.**in**(ids)).build().list();
```